# Workaround for busybox head that drops NUL from data

Tags: text-processing, busybox, binary

**TL;DR:** Latest busybox (1.23.2) provided `head` is buggy and will happily drop NUL characters in the provided data. Replacing the binaries is not an option. I'm using `head -[nc] -X` in my scripts, is there a way I can emulate it with other busybox-provided tools?

---

*People unfamiliar with file uploads and busybox httpd's handling of it may want to read [this](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/ZeptoOS/obsoletes/BGP-V1R3M0-merge-test/packages/busybox/src/networking/httpd_post_upload.txt) before continuing.*

I'm trying to process data uploads received by CGI scripts on an embedded system with Busybox installed. The sent data is the following:

```
$ hexdump -C foo.bin
00000000  03 15 20 00 00 00 75 73  74 61 72 30 30 30 2e 30  |.. ...ustar000.0|
00000010  00 11 00                                          |...|
00000013
```

When sent via a POST request, the CGI script that handles the data receives the following data:

```
$ hexdump -C 24593.tmp 
00000000  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  |----------------|
00000010  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 30 65 34 32 32 64  |----------0e422d|
00000020  63 39 65 64 65 32 34 36  34 30 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74  |c9ede24640..Cont|
00000030  65 6e 74 2d 44 69 73 70  6f 73 69 74 69 6f 6e 3a  |ent-Disposition:|
00000040  20 66 6f 72 6d 2d 64 61  74 61 3b 20 6e 61 6d 65  | form-data; name|
00000050  3d 22 66 69 6c 65 22 3b  20 66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d  |="file"; filenam|
00000060  65 3d 22 66 6f 6f 2e 62  69 6e 22 0d 0a 43 6f 6e  |e="foo.bin"..Con|
00000070  74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70  65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69  |tent-Type: appli|
00000080  63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6f  63 74 65 74 2d 73 74 72  |cation/octet-str|
00000090  65 61 6d 0d 0a 0d 0a 03  15 20 00 00 00 75 73 74  |eam...... ...ust|
000000a0  61 72 30 30 30 2e 30 00  11 00 0d 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d  |ar000.0.....----|
000000b0  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  |----------------|
000000c0  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 30 65  34 32 32 64 63 39 65 64  |------0e422dc9ed|
000000d0  65 32 34 36 34 30 2d 2d  0d 0a                    |e24640--..|
000000da
```

To retrieve the original data from the above is easy:

```
$ tail -n +5 24593.tmp | head -n -1 | head -c -2 | hexdump -C
00000000  03 15 20 00 00 00 75 73  74 61 72 30 30 30 2e 30  |.. ...ustar000.0|
00000010  00 11 00                                          |...|
00000013
```

However, busybox has a broken `head` and will drop all NUL characters in the data:

```
$ /firmware/system/xbin/tail -n +5 24593.tmp | /firmware/system/xbin/head -n -1 | /firmware/system/xbin/head -c -2 | hexdump -C
00000000  03 15 20 75 73 74 61 72  30 30 30 2e 30 11        |.. ustar000.0.|
0000000e
```

Is there any other method by which I can emulate the behaviour of `head -[nc] -X` (or atleast perform the job) with other tools provided by busybox?

---

<sup>The most prudent thing to do is to introduce/replace a new binary with the correct behaviour, but this can't be done for a number of reasons we don't have to go into here.</sup>

<sup>This post may also seem to be largely devoted at mentioning details that are irrelevant to the problem at hand, but I present the details here to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).</sup>

Comment: It seems to me that not only `head` is acting strange in the mentioned busybox release, but also `tail` and`awk`. What other tools are available on that firmware?

Comment: you should be using `dd` for this stuff - but i can't tell what you're doing. You strip the first five lines then... the last line? Then... the last two bytes? So you want all parts of a file which are not lines 1,5 or the last line or the last two bytes of the second to last line? Is there... a reason? I mean is there some method here?

Comment: @FloHimself - did you check that link?  The question isn;t clear about *why* we might want to read it, but the link is to a `bash` `while read` script. If it that loop is in on the action, it's a wonder there's not more missing.

Comment: @mikeserv if I get this right, all he want to do is extracting the binary file from the post request. Seen that link, but don't know if this really exact what he is doing or just an example of using bash scripts as `cgi`.

Comment: @FloHimself - I agree that it could be more clear. I'm confused as well. I looked at the script file and i *think* the 5lines, -1.2line thing lines up with those return delims in the <----- block. It might be as simple as `tr` and `cut`, but if `tail`, `head`, and `awk` are all busted, then who knows? You could write him a little main() for it probably, but the compiler would probably just disappoint.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract an uploaded file from a requests that consists of:

- a line consisting of dashes followed by hexadecimal digits;
- a bunch more non-empty lines (headers);
- an empty line;
- the content to extract;
- a line break;
- a repeat of the first line;

where line breaks are a CRLF sequence, and the content can contain arbitrary bytes, but the headers don't contain null bytes.

Rather than rely on `head` and `tail` to parse lines, you can do this in two steps:

1. Determine the range of byte positions that you want to extract.
2. Extract those bytes.

For the first step, to avoid problems with null bytes, use `tr` to translate them to something else. Then you can use a line-based tool to detect the first empty line and to detect the start of the last line. I use awk below, and take the opportunity to also extract the file name. If you don't have awk then you can use `head`, `tail`, `sed`, …

For the second step, you can use `dd` with a block size of 1. That's slow but reliable.

```
upload=24593.tmp
filename=$(<"$upload" tr '\0' _ | awk '
    {line_start = line_end; line_end += length($0)+1}
    !content_start && /^Content-Disposition:.*filename="/ {
        sub(/.*filename="/, ""); sub(/".*/, "");
        filename = $0
    }
    !content_start && $0=="\r" {content_start=line_end}
    END {print content_start, line_start-2-content_start, filename}
')
skip=${filename%% *}; filename=${filename#* }
count=${filename%% *}; filename=${filename#* }
if [ -z "$filename" ]; then filename=$(mktemp); fi
<$upload dd bs=1 skip="$skip" count="$count" >"$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Busybox is highly configurable, so the answer will depend on what was compiled in. Here are some options.

```
catv -v
```

will show nulls as `^@'.

```
split -l 1
```

will create files `xaa` `xab` etc each with one line in it.